# Get column index of clicked column in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, rowcommand

When a button in the footer is clicked how can the `HeaderText` or `ColumnIndex` or the clicked column be checked?

[image]

**GRIDVIEW**

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="Server" ShowFooter="true">
    <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="1">
        <ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSubmit1" runat="server" CommandName="Submit1">SUBMIT</asp:LinkButton>
        </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="2">
        <ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSubmit2" runat="server" CommandName="Submit2">SUBMIT</asp:LinkButton>
        </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="3">
        <ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSubmit3" runat="server" CommandName="Submit3">SUBMIT</asp:LinkButton>
        </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

**VB.NET**

```
  Private Sub gv_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gv.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Submit1" Then

      'GET CLICKED BUTTON
      Dim Button = TryCast(e.CommandSource, LinkButton)
      'GET CLICKED ROW
      Dim Row = TryCast(Button.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
      'GET CLICKED COLUMN
      '?
      'GET CLICKED COLUMN HEADER TEXT
      '?

    End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: Try that one Dim headerText As String = gv.Columns(1).HeaderText

Comment: @MMK you are correct I just worked this out myself too.

Comment: Glad you have worked this out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column is already determined by command name

```
Dim Column As String = sender.Columns(0).HeaderText
```